# React module return data object for supplied key. Only return length information

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to learn react. I am trying to figure out how to write a module that only returns the length information from the data I set up like this:

```
    function getVehicleLengthByVehicleId(id) {
            const ids = {
                "77 Travel Trailer, up to 35 ft.": {
                    min: 0,
                    max: 35
                },
                "78 Travel Trailers over 35, License plate, not affixed to property": {
                    min: 36,
                    max: Number.MAX_VALUE
                },
                "51 HS up to 35' length": {
                    min: 0,
                    max: 35
                },
                "51 HS over 35' thru 40' length": {
                    min: 36,
                    max: 40
                },
            }
           //look up code goes here

        }

export default getVehicleLengthByVehicleId;
```

I am trying to write the lookup code that will return just the length information. So I can do something like this:

```
import getLengthFromLabel from './modules/getVehicleLengthByVehicleId';

// write the code that makes this API possible:
getLengthFromLabel("77 Travel Trailer, up to 35 ft.");
//=> { min: 0, max: 35 }
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

I have tried doing something like this where it says //lookup code goes here

```
let curVal = ids[id];
    if (curVal && length >= curVal.min && length <= curVal.max) {
      // yes we found a match
      // alert('...')
    } else {
      // No we did not find a match
      // alert('...')
    }
```

But I am trying to return only the length information to be used as a module. I think I am confusing myself...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add in a return, with `id` being the key to the object `ids`

```
function getVehicleLengthByVehicleId(id) {
        const ids = {
            "77 Travel Trailer, up to 35 ft.": {
                min: 0,
                max: 35
            },
            "78 Travel Trailers over 35, License plate, not affixed to property": {
                min: 36,
                max: Number.MAX_VALUE
            },
            "51 HS up to 35' length": {
                min: 0,
                max: 35
            },
            "51 HS over 35' thru 40' length": {
                min: 36,
                max: 40
            },
        }
       return ids[id];

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`return ids[id];` should work. It will return `undefined` if no result found.